# How can I get ringtone setting for person in contact?

Tags: iphone

I search through AddressBook.sqlitedb and don't think it has such information.

So where can I get such Info or which api can I use to get it?

com.apple.springboard.plist just has ringbone set for all calls.

I just work with jailbreak iphones, so private api is ok.

Comment: I download an app called "AnyRing". With it I can set ringtone for each people in Contact. Does anybody know how it come out ?

Comment: I think it uses mobilesubstrate and its own configure file. This is just a guess =.=